# Ensure consistency over multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

I have following requirements:

- R1: Organisation units: super -> main -> child. They are linked hierarchical
- R2: An employe can report to: (super, main, child) or (super, main) or (super)
- Consistency:

  - R3: If an unit or its parent references an employee, they are not allowed to being moved
  - R4: employees must always reference to a consistent tree -> There must be a path from bottom to top / no foreign units are allowed to being referenced

Comments on my try:

- I don't think that i need to lock something for R3 - in worst case somebody changes an employee before COMMIT - but it should be still consistent
- R4 and R3 must work "together". Another solution would be to check check each affected employee after a change

Question: Can somebody review the solution in terms of concurrency correctness? The UPDATE example / test below worked as expected (2nd transaction was blocked) - but are there any other cases to test?

```
CREATE TABLE public.super
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE public.main
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  super_id_fkey BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES public.super(id),
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE public.child
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  main_id_fkey BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES public.main(id),
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE public.employee
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,    
  report_to_super_id_fkey BIGINT REFERENCES public.super(id),
  report_to_main_id_fkey BIGINT REFERENCES public.main(id),
  report_to_child_id_fkey BIGINT REFERENCES public.child(id),
  CHECK
  (
    (report_to_super_id_fkey IS NOT NULL) OR
    (report_to_super_id_fkey IS NOT NULL AND report_to_main_id_fkey IS NOT NULL) OR
    (report_to_super_id_fkey IS NOT NULL AND report_to_main_id_fkey IS NOT NULL AND report_to_child_id_fkey IS NOT NULL)
  )
);
```

Requirement 3:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_main_reference()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  AS $$
BEGIN  
  IF 
    (
      WITH data AS
      (
        SELECT public.super.id AS super_id, public.main.id AS main_id FROM public.super
        JOIN public.main ON public.main.super_id_fkey = public.super.id
        WHERE public.main.super_id_fkey = OLD.id
      )
      SELECT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT FROM public.employee WHERE
        EXISTS (SELECT FROM data WHERE employee.report_to_super_id_fkey = data.super_id) OR
        EXISTS (SELECT FROM data WHERE employee.report_to_main_id_fkey = data.main_id)
      )
    )
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Organizations units or child units having referenced employees can''t be moved';
  END IF;
   
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_child_reference()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  AS $$
BEGIN  
  IF 
    (
      WITH data AS
      (
        SELECT public.super.id AS super_id, public.main.id AS main_id, public.child.id AS child_id FROM public.super
        JOIN public.main ON public.main.super_id_fkey = public.super.id
        JOIN public.child ON public.child.main_id_fkey = public.main.id
        WHERE public.child.main_id_fkey = OLD.id
      )
      SELECT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT FROM public.employee WHERE
        EXISTS (SELECT FROM data WHERE employee.report_to_super_id_fkey = data.super_id) OR
        EXISTS (SELECT FROM data WHERE employee.report_to_main_id_fkey = data.main_id) OR
        EXISTS (SELECT FROM data WHERE employee.report_to_child_id_fkey = data.child_id)
      )
    )
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Organizations units or child units having referenced employees can''t be moved';
  END IF;
   
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_update_super_id_fkey 
BEFORE UPDATE OF super_id_fkey ON public.main
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (OLD.super_id_fkey IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.super_id_fkey)
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.check_main_reference();

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_update_child_main_id_fkey 
BEFORE UPDATE OF main_id_fkey ON public.child
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (OLD.main_id_fkey IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.main_id_fkey)
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.check_child_reference();
```

Requirement 4:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_hierarchy_consistency()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  AS $$
BEGIN
  -- We have to lock the referenced tree line - from top to bottom
  PERFORM FROM public.super WHERE id = NEW.report_to_super_id_fkey FOR NO KEY UPDATE;
  PERFORM FROM public.main WHERE id = NEW.report_to_main_id_fkey FOR NO KEY UPDATE;
  PERFORM FROM public.child WHERE id = NEW.report_to_child_id_fkey FOR NO KEY UPDATE;
 
  IF 
    (
      SELECT NOT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT FROM public.super
        LEFT JOIN public.main ON public.main.super_id_fkey = public.super.id
        LEFT JOIN public.child ON public.child.main_id_fkey = public.main.id
        WHERE
          (NEW.report_to_super_id_fkey IS NULL OR public.super.id = NEW.report_to_super_id_fkey) AND
          (NEW.report_to_main_id_fkey IS NULL OR public.main.id = NEW.report_to_main_id_fkey) AND
          (NEW.report_to_child_id_fkey IS NULL OR public.child.id = NEW.report_to_child_id_fkey)
      )
    )
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Reporting only to consistent hierarchy allowed';
  END IF;

 RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_update_employee_fkeys 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF report_to_super_id_fkey, report_to_main_id_fkey, report_to_child_id_fkey ON public.employee
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.check_hierarchy_consistency();
```

Testcase:

```
INSERT INTO public.super (name) VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3');

INSERT INTO public.main (super_id_fkey, name) VALUES
  (1, '1.1'), (1, '1.2'),
  (2, '2.1'), (2, '2.2'), (2, '2.3'),
  (3, '3.1'), (3, '3.2');

INSERT INTO public.child (main_id_fkey, name) VALUES
  ((SELECT id FROM public.main WHERE name = '1.1'), ('1.1.1')),
  ((SELECT id FROM public.main WHERE name = '1.1'), ('1.1.2')),
  ((SELECT id FROM public.main WHERE name = '1.2'), ('1.2.1')),
  ((SELECT id FROM public.main WHERE name = '2.1'), ('2.1.1'));
 
 
INSERT INTO public.employee (report_to_super_id_fkey, report_to_main_id_fkey, report_to_child_id_fkey) VALUES
(
    (SELECT id FROM public.super WHERE name = '1'),
    (SELECT id FROM public.main WHERE name = '1.1'),
    (SELECT id FROM public.child WHERE name = '1.1.2')
);
BEGIN;
  UPDATE public.employee SET report_to_child_id_fkey = (SELECT id FROM public.child WHERE name = '1.1.1') WHERE id = 1;
  -- Run on other session: UPDATE public.main SET super_id_fkey = (SELECT id FROM public.super WHERE name = '3') WHERE name = '1.1';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Please update your question to include: 1. An actual question. 2.What was the result when you ran. 3. Was an error generated. If so post the complete error message. 4. What is the expected results of your test data?  BTW Why use `Begin` before before the final update statement. It is not necessary and as it stands invalid as well.

Comment: I added the questions. I don't got an error (hope thats not the precondition for stackoverflow?!) - but I would kindly ask for a review if the requirements are met ;-)

The BEGIN was to show, that I kept the transaction "open", while i was doing the 2nd Update in another session

Comment: What do you mean by "*they are not allowed to being moved*"?

Comment: Since an employee can only report to *either* a super, main or child unit, you should add a check constraint that says only one of these can be non-null. If they report to a child unit, figure out the hierarchy by joining against the parent tables. If you want to store all three, use composite primary keys in the unit tables and composite foreign key references in the employee table.

Comment: Question 1: For e.g. "1.1.1" can't be moved to "2.1" (from 1.1) if referenced by an employee - no reorganization if employees reference a org-unit
Question 2: Thats not correct (see check constraint). R2 shows the requirements. 

"f they report to a child unit, figure out the hierarchy by joining against the parent tables" As you can see in my SP - I did ;-) The question is as always: which rows do I have to lock? Do I need to change the serialization level? Any other things to consider?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need these triggers if you use composite keys for your units and composite foreign key references for your employees:

```
CREATE TABLE public.super (
  id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.main (
  id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  super_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (super_id, id),
  FOREIGN KEY (super_id) REFERENCES public.super ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE public.child (
  id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  main_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  super_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (super_id, main_id, id),
  FOREIGN KEY (super_id, main_id) REFERENCES public.main ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE public.employee (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,    
  report_to_super_id BIGINT,
  report_to_main_id BIGINT,
  report_to_child_id BIGINT,
  CHECK (
    (report_to_super_id IS NOT NULL) OR
    (report_to_super_id IS NOT NULL AND report_to_main_id IS NOT NULL) OR
    (report_to_super_id IS NOT NULL AND report_to_main_id IS NOT NULL AND report_to_child_id IS NOT NULL)
  ),
  FOREIGN KEY (report_to_super_id) REFERENCES public.super ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE SET NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (report_to_super_id, report_to_main_id) REFERENCES public.main ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE SET NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (report_to_super_id, report_to_main_id, report_to_child_id) REFERENCES public.child ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/blAM4TzR))</sup>

With these foreign keys, R3 and R4 are guaranteed; you do not need to worry about transactions and race conditions.

Comment: I like your solution - never thought of that, representing a hierachy in such a way - nice.

The data duplication is ok, if the hierachy has only a depth of 3. How would you solve it >5? Are triggers for constraints too error prone?!